# Why not `{ let commonConfig = ...; in ...; }`?

Tags: nix, nixos

https://nixos.org/manual/nixos/stable/#sec-module-abstractions says:

> You can write a  `let`  wherever an expression is allowed. Thus, you
> also could have written:
>
> ```
> {
>   services.httpd.virtualHosts =
>     let commonConfig = ...; in
>     { "blog.example.org" = (commonConfig // { ... })
>       "wiki.example.org" = (commonConfig // { ... })
>     };
> }
> ```
>
> but not  `{ let commonConfig = ...; in ...; }`  since attributes (as
> opposed to attribute values) are not expressions.

Why not  `{ let commonConfig = ...; in ...; }`? What is the place where the `let` expression appears expected to be used for?

Are attributes the same as option names? Are attribute values the same as option values?

Answer (score 2):

> Are attributes the same as option names? Are attribute values the same as option values?

Notice at the very top and very bottom of the file-snippet are curly braces. Curly braces are the syntax for [attribute sets](https://nixos.org/manual/nix/stable/language/values#attribute-set) (attrsets) in the Nix language (like dictionaries or maps in other languages), and a `.nix` file is just one big Nix expression. A [NixOS Module](https://nixos.wiki/wiki/NixOS_modules) is a Nix expression that evaluates to an attrset. That attrset can have option names as *keys* in the attrset with their corresponding *values* set to the desired value for that NixOS option.

For example, a NixOS module like this:

```hs
{
  programs.zsh.enable = true;
}
```

sets the NixOS option `programs.zsh.enable` to `true` by having an attrset key called `programs.zsh.enable` set to `true`.

Attributes are not the same as option names, but option names are always attribute names.

---

Now, to your initial question. Why can't you put a `let` expression before the equals sign in an attrset? The answer to that is simply that the *key* side of an attrset isn't an arbitrary expression, just a name. If you have a function that returns a string, like this:

```hs
makeEnableName = program: "programs.${program}.enable";
```

You cannot have the attribute defined like this:

```hs
{
  (makeEnableName "zsh") = true;
}
```

The name side of every key-value pair in an attrset is just a name. It can be a quoted string, or an unquoted identifier, but it cannot be an arbitrary expression. And `let` expressions are indeed expressions!

The *value* side of a key-value pair in an attrset can be any arbitrary expression though, which means that is where the `let` needs to go.

Alternatively, you can also put the `let` *outside* of the attrset entirely, at the top of the file, like this:

```hs
let
  commonConfig = ...;
in {
  services.httpd.virtualHosts = {
    "blog.example.org" = (commonConfig // { ... });
  };
}
```